# Ontology file doesn't open by protege

Tags: xml, owl, protege

I got this error when I tried to open my ontology in protege

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/D:/iso_281.owl; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content ist nicht zulässig in Prolog.

Does anyone know how to solve it?
I build ontology for standard documents, can anyone help me to do it. here the first lines in file:

```
@prefix : <http://www.normendokumente/ISO/281/2010.owl#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@base <http://www.normendokumente/ISO/281/2010.owl#> .

<http://www.normendokumente/ISO/281/2010.owl> rdf:type owl:Ontology .

#################################################################
#    Annotation properties
#################################################################

###  http://www.normendokumente/ISO/281/2010.owl#rfs:beschränkung
:rfs:beschränkung rdf:type owl:AnnotationProperty .


###  http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#anmerkung
rdfs:anmerkung rdf:type owl:AnnotationProperty .


###  http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#randbedingung
rdfs:randbedingung rdf:type owl:AnnotationProperty .


###  http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#verweis
rdfs:verweis rdf:type owl:AnnotationProperty .


###  http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema# Hintergrundinformationen
<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema# Hintergrundinformationen> rdf:type owl:AnnotationProperty .


#################################################################
#    Object Properties
#################################################################

###  http://www.normendokumente/ISO/281/2010.owl#Ist_Anhang_Für
:Ist_Anhang_Für rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty .


###  http://www.normendokumente/ISO/281/2010.owl#Ist_Verweis_Für
:Ist_Verweis_Für rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty .
```

Comment: Hi, please add the first few lines of the file to the question so we can give meaningful answers. It looks like the file contains extraneous characters on the very first line.

Comment: prefix : <http://www.normendokumente/ISO/281/2010.owl#> .
prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
prefix xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace> .
prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
base <http://www.normendokumente/ISO/281/2010.owl#> .

<http://www.normendokumente/ISO/281/2010.owl> rdf:type owl:Ontology .

#################################################################
#    Annotation properties

Comment: 1) this is a Turtle file, it's better to use `.ttl` as file extension 2) as it is a Turtle file, the error message from the Turtle parsing attempt matters. 3) if you look it line 16, `:rfs:beschränkung rdf:type owl:AnnotationProperty .` is obviously wrong with the leading `:` - and you also messed up the prefix there with `rfs` given that all you other entries use `rdfs:` - please fix that line to `rdfs:beschränkung rdf:type owl:AnnotationProperty .

Comment: 4) `rdfs:` is usually the prefix for the namespace of RDFS, a reserved vocabulary - don't add classes, this is considered "ontology hijacking" and bad practice. Why are you not using you own namespace? 5) German class names look weird ... you should encode human readable names and languages in labels anyways. 6) common naming convention for classes is Pascal Case, e.g. `:Verweis` and for `properties it is camel case style, e.g. `:IstAnhangFür`

Comment: By the way, the error in line 16 happened most likely, because you manually edited the ontology file, why when you're using Protege?

Comment: Data is unstructured, so it's hard to build it automatic

Comment: If protege is asking for a file type, pick Turtle. If it's not asking for a file type, then there should be multiple errors as it tries multiple parsers. Scroll down until you find errors for the Turtle type, those will be the actual errors in your file. The rfs typo suggested by @UninformedUser is probably one of them.